# Firefox 43 auto-hides address bar "drop down arrow" - how to disable?

Tags: firefox

The newest Firefox (version 43) auto-hides the "drop down list arrow" in the address bar (so it only appears when you place the cursor over the address bar).  Is there a way to disable this (annoying) behavior?

Comment: Haven't tried it myself but the two comments here should help: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/2y0ph8/how_to_remove_drop_down_address_bar_arrow_icon/cp5v4ap

Comment: I'm very curious - why do you find this annoying?

Comment: @DavidPostill: I can't answer for the OP, but I find it annoying because now I have to actively think about where I'm moving the pointer rather than have a target that I seemingly didn't have to 'think' about. It may seem to be a small thing, and perhaps I'll adjust over time, but why?  That spot on the address bar isn't used for anything else - it stays blank even if the URL is longer than the address bar.  Why not just have the drop down arrow affordance there all the time? Why did the devs spend *any* time on this 'feature' that provides no benefit?

Comment: Why did the devs spend any time on this 'feature' that provides no benefit? --> +1

Comment: Note something missed from the reddit link is that you have to install the Stylish add-on. Also userChrome.css didn't work for me. Instead, I added the css via the Stylish add-on (after installing Stylish and restarting Firefox, I clicked the new Stylish button (just an "S"), then Manage Styles, then Write New Style).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your Firefox profile folder. This should be

```
<Home Directory>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<Profile Name>.default
```

where `<Home Directory>` is typically `C:\Users\<User Name>`.

You'll want to go into the `chrome` folder and create the file `userChrome.css` if it doesn't exist already. Add the code below to the file and save. You'll need to restart Firefox for the changes to have an effect.

To always **show** the arrow:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
#urlbar:not(:hover) > .urlbar-textbox-container > .urlbar-history-dropmarker {
opacity: 100 !important;
}
```

To always **hide** the arrow:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
.urlbar-history-dropmarker {
display: none !important;
}
```

Source: DOM Inspector
and [How to remove drop down address bar arrow icon?? : firefox](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/2y0ph8/how_to_remove_drop_down_address_bar_arrow_icon/cp5v4ap) at reddit.

Comment: A bit more involved than I like, but I'll take it!  Thanks!